# Python - if statement inside a list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm writing a piece of code that should take a list with several numbers (like this for example: `[2,3,5,6,6]`) and create a new list, removing all duplicates (to end up with `[2,3,5,6]`).

The code I have is this:

```
first_list = [2,3,5,6,6]
second_list = []
second_list = [x for x in first_list if x not in second_list]
```

However, it makes `second_list` equal to `first_list`, and I don't understand why. How can I make it do what I explained above?

Comment: None of the `x` are in the second list when the comprehension is evaluated for the simple reason that the second list is empty.

Comment: at the time your `second_list` would be empyt, it won't get updated during list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

The assignment to `second_list` happens **after** the list comprehension has completed.  It does not build `second_list` step by step.  What you wrote is equivalent to doing:

```
# this does not give the answer you want:
temp = [x for x in first_list if x not in second_list]
second_list = temp
```

This is because list comprehension builds the entire list in memory before is assigns it to `second_list`.  If you want to check the list as you build it, you can use a regular for loop with `append`.

```
second_list = []
for x in first_list:
    if x not in second_list:
        second_list.append(x)
```

For a faster method, use `set`:

```
second_list = list(set(first_list))
```

However, this does not necessarily preserve the order of `first_list`

Comment: It's not working...

Comment: The first code block is explaining why it will not work.  Use the second or third code block for the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

Just use sets instead of lists to remove duplicates:

```
first_list = [2,3,4,5,6,6]
first_set = set(first_list)
print(first_set)
```

sets cannot contain duplicates

Comment: I'm a beginner, so I didn't even know about sets. This works fine, thanks :)

Comment: This assumes that the order of the elements isn't relevant.

Comment: I just did  `newList = list(first_set) 

newList.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

To remove all duplicates, it is best to use set(), like this:

```
first_list = [2, 3, 5, 6, 6]
second_list = list(set(first_list))
```

Now, second_list contains all that you need

If you want to use for loops:

```
first_list = [2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6]
second_list = []
final_list = []
for i in first_list:
   if i not in second_list:
       final_list.append(i)
       second_list.append(i)

print final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain order, one way is to use an `OrderedDict` like:

**Code:**

```
second_list = OrderedDict([(x, None) for x in first_list]).keys()
```

**Test code:**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
first_list = [2, 3, 5, 6, 6]
second_list = OrderedDict([(x, None) for x in first_list]).keys()
print(second_list)
```

**Results:**

```
[2, 3, 5, 6]
```